# Error while scraping image with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**The original code is here :** https://github.com/amitabhadey/Web-Scraping-Images-using-Python-via-BeautifulSoup-/blob/master/code.py

So i am trying to adapt a Python script to collect pictures from a website to get better at web scraping.

I tried to get images from "https://500px.com/editors"

**The first error was**

> The code that caused this warning is on line 12 of the file/Bureau/scrapper.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 
>   'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

So I did :

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="lxml")
```

I also adapted the class to reflect the tag in 500px.

But now the script stopped running and nothing happened.

In the end it looks like this :

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib.request
import random 

url = "https://500px.com/editors"

source_code = requests.get(url)

plain_text = source_code.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="lxml")

for link in soup.find_all("a",{"class":"photo_link "}):
    href = link.get('href')
    print(href)

    img_name = random.randrange(1,500)

    full_name = str(img_name) + ".jpg"

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(href, full_name)

    print("loop break")
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you look at the value of `soup` you will see that there are no elements that match `img.photo_link`. This is likely due to the images being loaded via javascript. BeautifulSoup will parse the page, but doesn't really execute javascript. So the images are inaccessible to it. If this is a one off task, you can use your browser's DOM inspector and copy the html to a file to parse, but otherwise you might want to look into selenium.

Comment: By web tools development (network activity) in your browser that you are using you can see the photos loaded by javascript. You are looking for `api` - `https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?rpp=50&feature=editors`

Comment: I though so too, the URL used in the first script just load them directly, I tried with a different website and it is working, I assume that some website (500px, flickr, instagram) need a bit more work on the scraper to work.

Thanks

Comment: @Mcflan_7 check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the website is loaded via `JavaScript` using `XHR` request to the following [API](https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?rpp=50&feature=editors&image_size%5B%5D=1&image_size%5B%5D=2&image_size%5B%5D=32&image_size%5B%5D=31&image_size%5B%5D=33&image_size%5B%5D=34&image_size%5B%5D=35&image_size%5B%5D=36&image_size%5B%5D=2048&image_size%5B%5D=4&image_size%5B%5D=14&sort=&include_states=true&include_licensing=true&formats=jpeg%2Clytro&only=&exclude=&personalized_categories=&page=1&rpp=50)

So you can reach it directly via `API`.

> Note that you can increase parameter `rpp=50` to any number as you want for getting more than `50` result.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?rpp=50&feature=editors&image_size%5B%5D=1&image_size%5B%5D=2&image_size%5B%5D=32&image_size%5B%5D=31&image_size%5B%5D=33&image_size%5B%5D=34&image_size%5B%5D=35&image_size%5B%5D=36&image_size%5B%5D=2048&image_size%5B%5D=4&image_size%5B%5D=14&sort=&include_states=true&include_licensing=true&formats=jpeg%2Clytro&only=&exclude=&personalized_categories=&page=1&rpp=50").json()

for item in r['photos']:
    print(item['url'])
```

also you can access the image `url` itself in order to write it directly!

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?rpp=50&feature=editors&image_size%5B%5D=1&image_size%5B%5D=2&image_size%5B%5D=32&image_size%5B%5D=31&image_size%5B%5D=33&image_size%5B%5D=34&image_size%5B%5D=35&image_size%5B%5D=36&image_size%5B%5D=2048&image_size%5B%5D=4&image_size%5B%5D=14&sort=&include_states=true&include_licensing=true&formats=jpeg%2Clytro&only=&exclude=&personalized_categories=&page=1&rpp=50").json()

for item in r['photos']:
    print(item['image_url'][-1])
```

> Note that `image_url` `key` hold different `img` size. so you can choose your preferred one and save it. here I've taken the big one.

Saving directly:

```py
import requests

with requests.Session() as req:
    r = req.get("https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?rpp=50&feature=editors&image_size%5B%5D=1&image_size%5B%5D=2&image_size%5B%5D=32&image_size%5B%5D=31&image_size%5B%5D=33&image_size%5B%5D=34&image_size%5B%5D=35&image_size%5B%5D=36&image_size%5B%5D=2048&image_size%5B%5D=4&image_size%5B%5D=14&sort=&include_states=true&include_licensing=true&formats=jpeg%2Clytro&only=&exclude=&personalized_categories=&page=1&rpp=50").json()
    result = []
    for item in r['photos']:
        print(f"Downloading {item['name']}")
        save = req.get(item['image_url'][-1])
        name = save.headers.get("Content-Disposition")[9:]
        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(save.content)
```

Comment: Worked very well ! But let's say I want to download picture from my profile ? 
How could I modify the link ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page you're trying to scrape I noticed something. The data doesn't appear to load until a few moments after the page finishes loading. This tells me that they're using a JS framework to load the images after page load.

Your scraper will not work with this page due to the fact that it does **not** run JS on the pages it's pulling. Running your script and printing out what `plain_text` contains proves this:

```
<a class='photo_link {{#if hasDetailsTooltip}}px_tooltip{{/if}}' href='{{photoUrl}}'>
```

If you look at the `href` attribute on that tag you'll see it's actually a templating tag used by JS UI frameworks.

Your options now are to either see what APIs they're calling to get this data (check the inspector in your web browser for network calls, if you're lucky they may not require authentication) or to use a tool that runs JS on pages. One tool I've seen recommended for this is [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), though I've never used it so I'm not fully aware of its capabilities; I imagine the tooling around this would drastically increase the complexity of what you're trying to do.